# Can You Attend a Purim Party Dressed as a Pig?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Another thread inspired this question. Can one attend a Purim party or parade in a pig costume?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I think it would be worth it making this non-PTIJ.

Comment: If you do, bring a loaf of rye bread so you can have some "chazzir" rye.

Comment: I think the questions are degenerating. Just because it is Purim Torah should not give a license to ask any question. I think questions such as these are not appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ought to be forbidden as the pig is an impure animal and we are commanded to make a separation between our holy selves and impure beasts as we are instructed לְהַבְדִּיל בֵּין הַטָּמֵא וּבֵין הַטָּהֹר (Levit. 11:47). However, the gimatria of pig (חזיר) is הטהור (the pure one) this reveals that it too contains ניצוצי קדושה and intrinsic holiness which is why it will be permitted in the messianic age. Therefore, on Purim it would be permitted to dress up as a pig for it is really a pure kosher animal (deep down).

Comment: I thank you for your well thought-out answer. I was aware even as a young boy that cow's were holy, but I never quite realized that so are pigs. Holy Pig!!!